# Unable to place icons very near due to padding in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to have two icons/icon buttons as shown in the image. Due to padding there is always a space between them. how to remove the padding or is there another solution for this?[image]

Comment: can you include sample code-snippet that will reproduce the same example

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use svg image instead of material icons, https://www.iconpacks.net/free-icon/down-arrow-7425.html
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_svg

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Those specific icons use a lot of empty space.
I would recreate this effect by using a stack and offsetting the two icons.

I quickly put this together. Hope it helps.

[image]

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      width: 40,
      height: 40,
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Color(0x00FFFFFF),
      ),
      child: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0.4),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_drop_down,
              color: Color(0xFF797979),
              size: 24,
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, -0.4),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.arrow_drop_up,
              color: Color(0xFFAAAAAA),
              size: 24,
            ),
          ),
          Align(
            child: Column(
              children: [
                InkWell(
                  onTap: (){},
                  child: Container(
                    width: 40,
                    height: 20,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0x00FFFFFF),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                InkWell(
                  onTap: (){},
                  child: Container(
                    width: 40,
                    height: 20,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      color: Color(0x00FFFFFF),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. This helped me in placing the icons near but in case of icon buttons the onTap is not working as expected for the bottom button

Comment: I added a new layer with two containers on top. Each have their own onTap. This should give you your desired functionality.